Why does GridDB return an error when querying a time-series container with a date range filter?
I am working on an IoT application using GridDB to store and query time-series data. My setup involves a time-series container with temperature sensor readings. Here's the issue:
When I run the following query to filter records within a specific date range:
SELECT * FROM sensor_data WHERE timestamp >= TIMESTAMP('2023-12-01T00:00:00Z') AND timestamp < TIMESTAMP('2023-12-02T00:00:00Z'); 
I get this error:
Error code: XXXXXX - Invalid range filter specified for time-series container.
What I've tried:
-Verified that the timestamp column is indexed.
-Checked the container schema to ensure the timestamp column is of the TIMESTAMP type.
-Simplified the query to check if it works without a filter, and it retrieves all records successfully.
-Tried using different date formats, but the issue persists.
Environment Details:
-GridDB Version: 5.0
-OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
-Client SDK: Python
What could be causing this error in a date range query for a time-series container?
Are there any specific configurations or constraints in GridDB for handling time-series queries that I might be missing?
